# How do you align the edges of sprites?

Tags: c++, sprites, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

If you have SpriteA and SpriteB.

SpriteB is a child of SpriteA.

Does anyone have a mechanism to come up with the left, right, top, side of a boundingbox() of SpriteA?

What I'd like to do is align SpriteB with the edge of SpriteA. Right now when created, SpriteB is centered with SpriteA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To position SpriteB to be aligned with SpriteA you just need to do a little math. Getting the bounds will return a rectangle. From that rectangle, you can get the width and height of the bounding box. Combine that with the position and you can get the location of the points you're interested in.

[image]

For example, the distance to move the sprite to align it with the left edge can be calculated by finding the distance between the edges. The difference between the purple and blue point can be found with `(A_Post.x - A_Bounds.Width/2) - (B_Pos.x - B_Bounds.Width/2)`. Similarly, you can find something like the right edge difference with `(A_Post.x + A_Bounds.Width/2) - (B_Pos.x + B_Bounds.Width/2)`.

Move the sprite by that amount and you'll have it sharing its left bounds with the bounds of SpriteA.

Comment: I am just a little confused by your use of `*_Bounds.Width` is there a `width` function from `boundingbox()`? Should it be content size?

Comment: I wrote it in pseudo code (I haven't used Cocos). If there's not a `width` property, then something like `size.x` would be the same thing if that's available.